# How to display an image from documents directory to UIImageView in Swift 3?

Tags: swift3

The below Swift 2 example gives this error:

> Value of type String has no member 'stringByAppendingPathComponent'

[image: Screenshot of Error]

What do I need to change for Swift 3?

Comment: Type the error in the body of your question instead of linking a screenshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple is trying to move everyone off the path-as-string paradigm to URL (i.e. `file:///path/to/file.text`). The Swift API pretty much removes all `path` in favor of `URL`.

You can still find it in Objective-C (`NSString`):

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let getImagePath = NSString.path(withComponents: [paths, "fileName"])
```

The more Swifty way:

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent("fileName")
```

Comment: swift error when try to place on UIImageView:  "cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'" in: myImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFIle: url)

Comment: If you decide the use URL, call the `path` property to get the path as string: `myImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFIle: imageUrl.path)`

Answer (score 1):

I personally like getting of this value from the App delegate. Put this code (stands alone like normal function) into the AppDelegate.swift.

```
lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()
```

So in all your files you can use it this way:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let imageUrl = appDelegate.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("YourFileName")
    let imageUrlString = imageUrl.urlString //if String is needed
```

Comment: getting error value of type 'URL' has no member 'urlString'.  If I don't use that but instead use imageUrl then I get  "cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String'" in: myImage.image =  UIImage(contentsOfFIle: imageUrl)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i posted swift 3 code written on Xcode 8 Beta 6. It was the first time a had to to use member urlString, as updated SDK requests it.